# How to force minimize an application when keyboard is hijacked?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.04, window

**Background**: I play one game sometimes on Linux (http://aao25.com). Although it's a very good multiplayer game, there are very few players because it's oldish, so it sometimes requires to join a server and wait for other players to come. Problem is, I can't figure out a way to minimize the game Window, even if I have it in widowed mode (everything else is visible around), the keyboard and mouse is completely hijacked by the game. The only combination that works is to go to `tty` console by pressing `Ctrl + F1 / F5 / F6`, but I don't know a way to focus a specific application from there upon return.

**Question**: Is there any certain way to minimize a currently open application window? Either through `tty` console or directly.

Just to show you how frustrating this looks, here's a photo of my desktop:
[image]

Comment: Does ALT+TAB work?

Comment: No, hijacked. Even the power button on the physical PC does not respond to single click (just the long one for power cut)

Comment: Same question in the game forum: http://aao25.com/forum/assist-support/how-to-have-game-minimized/

Comment: Yes, `Xorg`. But I would have to have `terminal` focused for it to work, no? .. In which case the problem would be already solved by then.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoDeletedHisComment, `wmctrl` looked nice, except from `tty` it "Cannot open display" - that's the output from the program.

Comment: @JacobVlijm .. in that you control the view in game (look around) instead of controlling the desktop mouse. Never seen a First Person Shooter?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `tty` :

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then get the ID of your application through:

```
wmctrl -l
```

it will list ID of all opened window . e,g: The id of your application is `0x02e00010` , to minimize the window run:

```
xdotool windowminimize 0x02e00010
```

Or :

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

Comment: It turns out you can just do `xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize`, no need to know window number..